# possible solution that dealing with result end up with "(RealFrac a,Integral a)=>a"

Tags: haskell

```
ts ::(RealFrac a,Integral a)=>a
ts =5 

ghci > ts
 * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in `Data.Either'
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        ...plus 24 others
        ...plus 80 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I know it can be solve by avoid using some function together to prevent the result with constrain `(RealFrac a,Integral a)` togather, but is there any other possible way to solve it that only dealing with the result?

Comment: How did you arrive at `(RealFrac a, Integral a)`? Are you trying to make a value that can be used as *either* `RealFrac` or `Integral`? In that case, you may just want `(Num a)` instead. As [Robin Zigmond’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763941/246886) says, there is no standard type that is an instance of *both* `RealFrac` and `Integral`, which is what your constraint demands.

Comment: You say you encounter this problem "coding some program relate to the rounding"... at a guess, do you have some fractional numbers and you're applying `round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b` to them (or `ceiling` or `floor`), but then trying to add/multiply/whatever the results with your fractional numbers? That won't work; `round` produces a different output type (an `Integral` one) than its input type, but the basic arithmetic operators only work with the same type on both sides. You would need to use `fromIntegral` to turn your rounded numbers back into the same type.

Comment: I accidentally made a program doing like this ```round $  n/2```(in List comprehension),  and passed without error until put in ghci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem GHCi has here is simply that it doesn't know what type to use for `ts`. All it knows it that it has to be an instance of `RealFrac` and of `Integral` - and also of `Show` (since asking for a result to be displayed in GHCi implicitly requires a `Show instance, so GHCi knows how to display it as a string in your terminal). And this isn't enough for it to know exactly which type to use - which is what it is complaining about.

The usual way to solve this is to specify the type you want explicitly, such as (note that this will NOT work as I explain below, but it shows the usual way to solve such an "ambiguous type variable" error in GHCi):

```
ts :: Int
```

As I said, this won't work, because the type you choose has to be compatible with the signature of `ts` - which here means it has to be an instance of both `RealFrac` and `Integral`. (And `show`, as I mentioned.) `Int` is not an instance of `RealFrac`, so GHCi will complain about this if you try the above.

Unfortunately for you, there is NO type which has instances of both `RealFrac` and `Integral` in the standard library. This wouldn't really make sense anyway, because `Integral` is for things which behave like whole numbers, and `RealFrac` for things which behave like non-whole numbers. But that doesn't stop you, in theory, writing instances of both for a particular type. Or writing an instance of `RealFrac` for say `Int`, or `Integral` for say `Double` - it's hard to see how such an instance would have value, but Haskell doesn't rule it out. (You will need to supply the necessary superclass instances too, such as `Real` and `Fractional` for `RealFrac`, and `Real` and `Enum` for `Integral`.)

So it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here. But that's why you're getting errors - to summarise:

1. GHCi needs an explicit type to work with before it is able to display a result
2. this can normally be solved by providing one, in cases like this where GHCi doesn't have enough information to work it out itself
3. in this example though, there are basically no such types you can provide (without doing a bit of work to write a bunch of instances which will basically make no sense anyway)

Comment: so this error is causing by unable to find the "match-able" Show instance?  
Still,   is ```prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved``` means " do not use ```Show``` for this variable? and do the  ```These potential instances exist:   and out-of-scope types``` mean for " potential solution for your variable?(despite they won't solve the problem)